# Razor on Core 6 - How to use pagination when already using a filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, filter, pagination

a newbie question. I'm currently learning Razor pages on Core 6. I have a working page that shows me hundreds of items. I can filter those items using a form on my .cshtml page which has something like:

```
<form>
  <p>
     Name:<input-type="text" asp-for="Name"/>
     <input type="submit" value=Filter">
  </p>
</form>
```

This works great. In reality I have more than just Name that I filter on but I want to keep the question as simple as possible.

When I click the Filter button and the filtered results are shown I see that the url in the addressbar now contains the value (eg 'bob') for the filter:

```
localhost:xxxx/Test?Name=bob
```

Happy with the results so far I decided to add pagination as well. In my .cshtml file I have this code:

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= Model.TotalPages; i++)
{
   <li class="page-item">
      <a asp-page="index" asp-route-currentpage="@i" class="page-link">@i</a>
   </li>
}
```

If I move my mouse over the buttons 1,2,3, etc. for the pages I now see that eg button 2 links to:

```
localhost:xxxx/Test?currentpage=2
```

Which is good but makes me lose the filter 'name=bob' that I already had. What do I need to do so that the button links to:

```
localhost:xxxx/Test?Name=bob&currentpage=2
```

instead? I would assume there is some way to retrieve/keep the current filter (Name=bob) and just add the 'currentpage=2' to it.

If I adjust the url manually to the one above the results are exactly as I need them to be (the second page of the filtered (Name=bob) results). So that's all working fine, I just don't know how to have the current filter in the route for the link.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Encaspsulate a `paginatedlist` class separately ,and call it in controller.

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

        public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

            this.AddRange(items);
        }

        public bool HasPreviousPage => PageIndex > 1;

        public bool HasNextPage => PageIndex < TotalPages;

        public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
    }
```

Use the search string and page number as the parameters of index, like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageNumber)
{
}
```

For more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

And all code is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/data/ef-mvc/intro/samples/cu-final).